# Show $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \le 2$ and $\ln(n!) \ge 1 -n+n\ln(n)$ for all positive integers n

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction, integers

I have been trying to show these two inequalities hold for all positive integers n, but I don't know how to proceed at all... I have tried playing around with them but I didn't find anything helpful. I have also tried induction but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Calculus for the second one? If so, think about $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln k$ and $\int_{1}^{n}\ln x\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first inequality:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}&\leq 1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k(k-1)}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\\
&=1+1-\dfrac{1}{n}\\
&<2.
\end{align*}

By looking at the upper sum, we see that 
\begin{align*}
\log(n!)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log k\\
&\geq\int_{1}^{n}\log udu\\
&=u\log u\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=n}-\int_{1}^{n}1du\\
&=n\log n-n+1.
\end{align*}