# Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction

The method I used: Mathematical induction

I am aware that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Wanted to find a general proof than going from that level of specificity.

It is trivial to prove the case for $n=1$

We need to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 \implies \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 \tag{1}$$

Assuming $$\sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 \tag{2}$$
Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \tag{3}$$

We know, $$p \geq 1 $$
$$ p+1 \geq 2 $$
$$ (p+1)^2 \geq 4 $$
$$ \frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \leq \frac{1}{4} $$
$$ 2+\frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \leq 2+\frac{1}{4} \tag{4}$$

By inequalities 3 and 4:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \leq 2+\frac{1}{4} \tag{5}$$

Therefore we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 \implies \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 +\frac{1}{4} \tag{6}$$
Anything I've missed to reach statement 1?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2942012/42969.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024530/42969 in  [Examples where it is easier to prove more than less](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007256/42969).

Comment: $\frac  1 {k^{2}}<\frac 1 {k-1} -\frac 1 k$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2709889/42969